# formula is not giving me "01"

Tags: excel

I am new to excel and for now I am working on a leave tracking template for staff. but the problem I am facing is that when i added a column to the left side of my sheet(ID column) the first date cell turned into "02"( the second day of the month) but I want it to be "01". I have tried but I could not change that. so I was wondering if anybody could help me.
this is my function : 
*$B$3 and $B$1 cells are equal to 1 and $B$2 is equal to 2016 
just to make it clear my first column(A) was name and my second column(B) was "01" (or the first day of the month generating by the below function). and the third column (C) was "02" and so on... but after adding a column for ID before the name column I could not see "01" no more.

```
=IF(AND((COLUMN()-1)>31*($B$3-1),MONTH(DATE($B$2+INT(($B$3+$B$1)/12),INT((COLUMN()-1)/31.001)+$B$1,ROUNDUP(MOD(COLUMN()-1,31.001),0)))=ROUNDUP(MOD($B$1+$B$3-1,12.01),0)),ROUNDUP(MOD(COLUMN()-1,31.001),0),"")
```

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: Please, attach sheet captured image to understand

Comment: screenshot is attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula has the **column()** function which literally depends on the column number. So when you inserted a new column to the left, the column part of the formula increased by 1.

Since you added one new column, change all your **COLUMN()-1** to **COLUMN()-2** and the formula should give you the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
=IF(AND((COLUMN()-2)>31*($B$3-1),MONTH(DATE($B$2+INT(($B$3+$B$1)/12),INT((COLUMN()-2)/31.001)+$B$1,ROUNDUP(MOD(COLUMN()-2,31.001),0)))=ROUNDUP(MOD($B$1+$B$3-1,12,01),0)),ROUNDUP(MOD(COLUMN()-2,31.001),0),"")
```